# Accessing one element in a has many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

I have two classes with one-to-many relationship. For example:

```
class User 
  has_many :numbers
  ...
end
```

How can I access one individual number that user has without using for or each? I tried `user.numbers[2]` and it didn't work (I was thinking it's like using a basic array but apparently it's not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find the user

```
user = User.find(1) or user = User.first
user.numbers.first   #this will return the first associated object
```